# I am creating a mockup cinema website for my school project. I've got some issues related to "select" forms and JavaScript codes

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm now creating a dropdown list to select a set of date, time and house for a show. I have three options in the list, namely, "--Choose date, time and house--","20 Aug 2019, 11:30 am, House 1" and "22 Aug 2019, 4:30 pm, House 2". However, the expected outcome for each of the options when submitted is not realised. (For context, EP is the initials of a movie title.)

I've tried using separate if statements and not if else statements, but that's not helping either.

```
<form onsubmit= recordEPDateTime()>
    <select  id="EPDateTime" style="width: 550px;">
        <option name="choose">--Choose date, time and house--</option> 
        //Default option that tells users to choose a show
        <option name="20Aug201911:30amh1">20 Aug 2019, 11:30 am, House 1</option> 
        //Details of first show
        <option name="22Aug20194:30pmh2">22 Aug 2019, 4:30 pm, House 2</option> 
        //Details of second show
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Choose Seats">
</form>

<br>

<script language="javascript">
    var details="";
    function recordEPDateTime (){
        details = document.getElementById(EPDateTime);
        if(details="20Aug201911:30amh1"){
            window.open("EP20AugHouse1.html");
        }
        //Opens a web page to the house layout of first show
        else if(details="22Aug20194:30pmh2"){
            window.open("EP22AugHouse2.html");
        }
        //Opens a web page to the house layout of second show
        else{
            window.alert("Select a show first.");
        }
        //Displays a window alert that they must choose a show first.
    ;}
</script>
```

When I click the submit button, I expected to have the first option to display an alert message, the second option to open a window to EP20AugHouse1.html, and the third option to open a window and go to EP22AugHouse2.html

But it seems that no matter which option I choose, when I pressed the submit button it would always open a window to EP20AugHouse1.html, which is the expected result for the second option (20 Aug 2019, 11:30 am, House 1), but not the other two.
Can anyone help and tell me what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For HTML, you must wrap comments within `<!-- comment -->`.
- Option has no "name" attribute.
- and the rest is as @undef_user mentioned before.

```js
const recordEPDateTime = () => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const s = event.target.elements['select'];
  const ov = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
  
  if (!!ov) {
    window.alert('Will open /' + ov + '.html');
  } else {
    window.alert('Select an option first.');
  }
};
```

```html
<form onsubmit="recordEPDateTime()">
    <select  id="EPDateTime" name="select">
        <option value>-Select-</option><!-- Default option that tells users to choose a show -->
        <option value="EP20AugHouse1">20 Aug 2019, 11:30 am, House 1</option><!-- Details of first show -->
        <option value="EP22AugHouse2">22 Aug 2019, 4:30 pm, House 2</option><!-- Details of second show -->
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Choose Seats">
</form>
```

Comment: Yes! Code worked just as I wanted, I only had to modify a few lines (such as rewriting window.alert to window.open for the non-"Choose an option" options as well as the values of the options. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't compare details and its value, you assigned the new value. In this case, if statement always returns true. For comparison use `==` or `===`: `if(details === "20Aug201911:30amh1") {...}`.

Also, `id` should be in quotes: `document.getElementById('EPDateTime')` or you need to create `EPDateTime` variable with id as a string.

But I rewrote the code in a bit different way:

```
<form>
  <select  id="EPDateTime" style="width: 550px;">
    <option name="choose">--Choose date, time and house--</option> 
    //Default option that tells users to choose a show
    <option name="20Aug201911:30amh1">20 Aug 2019, 11:30 am, House 1</option> 
    //Details of first show
    <option name="22Aug20194:30pmh2">22 Aug 2019, 4:30 pm, House 2</option> 
    //Details of second show
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Choose Seats">
</form> 

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', event => {
  const select = document.querySelector('select');

  [...select].map(el => {
    if (el.selected) {
      const name = el.getAttribute('name');

      if (name === '20Aug201911:30amh1') {
        window.open('EP20AugHouse1.html');
      } else if (name === '22Aug20194:30pmh2') {
        window.open('EP22AugHouse2.html');
      } else if (name === 'choose') {
        window.alert('Select a show first.');
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've copied the <script> code into my website, however the page only reloads when I click the button. Is there something that I need to replace in the code?